# How to get text extraction from PDF to work?

Tags: java, pdf, unicode

I need to extract the text from a PDFs in Romanian language. The symbols: ȚțȘșĂăÎîÂâ are not extracted correctly with pdfBox or Snowtide.

Here is a sample file that is not working:
ftp://ftp.logos.md/Biblioteca/_Colectie_RO/2nefon.pdf

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide a sample PDF. Probably the PDFs in question do not provide the information required for text extraction according to the spec.

Comment: This PDF: ftp://ftp.logos.md/Biblioteca/_Colectie_RO/2nefon.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid the PDF the OP pointed at ([2nefon.pdf](ftp://ftp.logos.md/Biblioteca/_Colectie_RO/2nefon.pdf)) does not provide the information required for text extraction according to the spec.

Trying to copy&paste from Adobe Reader results in the special characters being incorrectly exported, and as Adobe Reader contains quite good text extraction capabilities, this already is a bad sign.

Inspecting the file shows the problems. E.g. let's look at the title

[image: Screen shot of the title of 2nefon.pdf]

The corresponding segment of the content stream is:

```
/F1 24 Tf
-148.44 -26.16 TD
(VIA}A  {I  ~NV|}|TURILE) Tj
296.88 0 TD
( ) Tj
-308.16 -29.28 TD
(SFANTULUI  IERARH  NIFON) Tj
```

Let's check the used font **F1**:

```
469 0 obj
<< 
/Type /Font 
/Subtype /TrueType 
/Name /F1 
/BaseFont /TimesR 
/FirstChar 32 
/LastChar 255 
/Widths [ 250 333 444 722 500 833 778 [...] 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 ] 
/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding 
/FontDescriptor 468 0 R 
>> 
endobj
```

Thus, the font claims to use **WinAnsiEncoding** without changes (no **Differences**).

A last look at the font descriptor:

```
468 0 obj
<< 
/Type /FontDescriptor 
/FontName /TimesR 
/Flags 34 
/FontBBox [ -167 -307 1009 913 ] 
/StemV 90 
/ItalicAngle 0 
/CapHeight 913 
/Ascent 913 
/Descent -307 
/FontFile2 474 0 R 
>> 
endobj
```

No hint here that the afore mentioned **WinAnsiEncoding** might not be the whole truth.

According to the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)

> A conforming reader can use these methods, in the priority given, to map a character code to a Unicode value. Tagged PDF documents, in particular, shall provide at least one of these methods (see 14.8.2.4.2, "Unicode Mapping in Tagged PDF"):
>
> - If the font dictionary contains a **ToUnicode** CMap (see 9.10.3, "ToUnicode CMaps"), use that CMap to convert the character code to Unicode.
> - If the font is a simple font that uses one of the predefined encodings **MacRomanEncoding**, **MacExpertEncoding**, or **WinAnsiEncoding**, or that has an encoding whose **Differences** array includes only character names taken from the Adobe standard Latin character set and the set of named characters in the Symbol font (see Annex D):
>
>   a)Map the character code to a character name according to Table D.1 and the font’s **Differences** array.
>
>   b)Look up the character name in the Adobe Glyph List (see the Bibliography) to obtain the corresponding Unicode value.
> - If the font is a composite font [... cut short because the font **F1** is no composite font ...]
>
> If these methods fail to produce a Unicode value, there is no way to determine what the character code represents in which case a conforming reader may choose a character code of their choosing.
>
> *(section 9.10.2 Mapping Character Codes to Unicode Values)*

So text extraction and copying&pasting are completely following the specification when reporting that the document claims those two lines say:

```
VIA}A {I ~NV|}|TURILE
SFANTULUI IERARH NIFON
```

You might want to check, though, whether e.g. **Ă** (capital A with brevis) is always exported as **|**; this actually is not unlikely, mapping special characters to character codes of symbols was quite common for a time in the last century. If that indeed is the case, a global search&replace after text extraction gives you the desired text.

Answer (score -2):

How about iText: http://itextpdf.com/

"iText® is an open source library that allows you to create and manipulate PDF documents. It enables developers looking to enhance web- and other applications with dynamic PDF document generation and/or manipulation."