# Acrobat Reader search fails for odd characters

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I came across some odd characters in a PDF file. I tried to search to see if there were more, but Adobe Reader's search didn't even find the instance that I cut and pasted from to start the search. What??  I used both the Control-F search and the full Control-Shift-F search.

Can someone help me understand why I can't search for these characters?
The computer I'm using is Windows 7, 64 bit, US English locale settings.

The example text below should read "**system's current state.**"

[image: Picture of odd characters]

If it matters, I believe these odd characters are an artifact of Microsoft Word's "Smart Quotes". I can make them go away by not cutting and pasting from Word to the XSD/LaTex PDF generation tool my coworker set up. But I want to understand why Acrobat Reader won't let me find instances of them via search.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402741/how-to-get-text-extraction-from-pdf-to-work (Note that text search in PDF is equivalent to text extraction)

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you copy&pasted the search phrase from the document itself (and it looked good), inserted it in the search text box, and that search did not result in hits? In that case it's not the identical issue as the one @yms pointed to. Very likely, though, those issues are related. If you want details, please share the PDF in question for analysis.

Comment: @mkl Yes, I copied and pasted from the PDF itself, and the Find feature did not find the source text I copied from, even though it displayed identically to my eye. I'm guessing it is somehow related to the extraction link provided by yms. Long and short of it is I know how to not have the issue in the first place (don't let Word smartquotes into your source document), I was just curious why I couldn't find something I cut and pasted into the Find dialog within Acrobat Reader.